# Standard way to do strcmp with alternative terminating characters?

Tags: c, string, parsing, string-matching

So I have a string like so:

```
char* line="foo bar\tbaz\nbiz";
```

I want to parse this string one word at a time, doing different things depending on the word. Something like this:

```
void process_word(const char* str) //str will point to the beginning of a word
{
  if(!strcmp(str, "foo")){
    foo();
  }else if(!strcmp(str, "bar")){
    bar();
  }else{
    others();
  }
}
```

How would I do this so that I can use something like strcmp so that instead of it stopping comparison at \0, instead stopping at a space or other whitespace character?

Bonus points for no new buffer creation or overkill solutions like regular expressions

Comment: do you need `strtok()`,what is `str`?  is it `foo bar biz baz` ?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan strtok is out, since I really need the string to not be changed (since it could be used later on down the line.. and I'd rather not allocate a second buffer for it)

Comment: @Eartz then `strstr()`?

Answer (score 0):

This would just check the pattern, regardless of the word termination character

```
int mystrncmp(const char *line, const char *pattern)
{
   int len = strlen(pattern);
   return strncmp(line,pattern,len);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define WHITE_SPACE " \t\n"

int strcmp2ws(const char *s1, const char *s2){
    size_t len1, len2;
    len1 = strcspn(s1, WHITE_SPACE);
    len2 = strcspn(s2, WHITE_SPACE);

    return strncmp(s1, s2, (len1 <= len2) ? len2 : len1);
}

int main(void){
    char* line="foo bar\tbaz\nbiz";
    //test
    if(!strcmp2ws(line, "foo"))
        printf("foo\n");
    if(!strcmp2ws(strchr(line, ' ') + 1, "bar"))
        printf("bar\n");
    if(!strcmp2ws(strchr(line, '\t') + 1, "baz"))
        printf("baz\n");
    if(!strcmp2ws(strchr(line, '\n') + 1, "biz"))
        printf("biz\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: note: I will go well with this in most cases is larger than the spaces (0x20) is a normal character. However, there are times when it does not operate strictly true because it is a simple method to this. E.g. `strcmp2ws("abc\x7", "abc")`. It is not possible simply to replace in case of any `WHITE_SPACE` other than for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

The function strcspn gives the length of a string up to a set of "reject" characters. Combining that with strncmp should give you what you want.

```
#include <string.h>

const char delimiters = " \t\n";

void process_word(const char* str, size_t len) //str will point to the beginning of a word
{
  if(!strncmp(str, "foo", len)){
    foo();
  }else if(!strncmp(str, "bar", len)){
    bar();
  }else{
    others();
  }
}

void parse(const char *s)
{
    size_t i, len;

    i = 0;
    while (s[i] != '\0') {
        len = strcspn(&s[i], delimiters);
        process_word(&s[i], len);
        i += len;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution:

```
const char* next_word_is(const char* haystack, const char* needle) {
  size_t len = strlen(needle);
  const char* end = &haystack[len];
  if (strncmp(haystack, needle, len) == 0 && (!*end || isspace(*end)))
    return end;
  return NULL;
}
```

If you call that with a string literal as the second argument, it will probably get inlined, and the `strlen()` call will be eliminated. Returning `end` as a success indicator may not be ideal; depending on your needs, you might want to advance to the beginning of the next word instead.